# How to prove ⌈AB⌉=⌈⌈A⌉⌈B⌉⌉

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Given that we denote ⌈R⌉, the matrix obtained by replacing all of R's nonzero entries with a 1. Then prove for a n by n non-negative matrices A and B with positive diagonal elements, that ⌈AB⌉=⌈⌈A⌉⌈B⌉⌉. Please help me proving it.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB$ has a non-zero entry at $i,j$, then necessarily we have $a_{i,k}b_{k,j}\ne 0$ for at least one $k$. In fact, as all entries are non-negartive, no cancellation can occur in sums, which means that this "if" is in fact an "if and only if".
But whether or not $a_{i,k}b_{k,j}\ne 0$ does not change if we replace non-zeroes by $1$.